# Redirect an URL with all variables to another URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect a URL to another URL. So far I have done this in the .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/mypage.php http://newdomain.com/mynewpage
```

This works fine, but it copies the GET variables in the new URL as well. So I end up with

http://domain.com/mypage.php?item=32

being redirected to:

http://newdomain.com/mynewpage?item=32

I want remove all the variables in the new ULR. I know that this has to be done somehow with mod_rewrite, but I am struggling a lot with it and can not make it work.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,I got it myself... here is what I have done:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?
```